# Dynamically assigning variables oracle sql

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

I have a table attribute_config with below columns:

table_name column_name key

Let us say is has below 2 rows

account    accountphone accountnum

customer   customernumber customerid

Key can be only accountnum or customerid.

I have to write code which will accept (i_accountnum,i_customerid) and;

fetch the respective values from columns mentioned in column_name in tables mentioned in table_name using the key in where condition.

For ex: select accountphone from account where accountnum = i_accountnum
    select customernumber from customer where customerid = i_customerid

the complete query should be formed dynamically, whether to pass i_accountnum or i_customerid in the query also needs to be decided dynamically. if key - accountnum, i_accountnum will be passed to where condition.

I have been trying on these lines so far, this is not working, i know it is wrong.

```
declare
v_accountnum varchar2(20);
v_customerid varchar2(20);
v_attribute_value varchar2(20);
v_stmt varchar2(255);
begin
Account_Num := 'TestCustomer';  -- input to the function
v_customer_ref := 'TestAccount'; -- input to the function
for i in (Select * from attribute_config) loop
v_stmt := 'select ' || i.column_name || ' from ' ||  i.table_name ||' where ' || i.key|| ' = v_' || i.key;
execute immediate v_Stmt into v_attribute_value;
end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your code, but I do not see any advantage of using dynamic query when your code should accept 2 parameters(i_accountnum,i_customerid) - which is already static situation and fetch the relevant values, perhaps only in learning purposes.

```
declare
   procedure fecth_values(i_accountnum account.accountnum%type,
                          i_customerid customer.customerid%type) return varchar2 is
      v_attribute_value varchar2(20);
   begin
      for i in (select * from attribute_config) loop
         execute immediate 'select ' || i.column_name || ' from ' ||
                           i.table_name || ' where ' || i.key || ' = ' || case when i.key = 'accountnum' then i_accountnum when i.key = 'customerid' then i_customerid end;
         into v_attribute_value;
         dbms_output.put_line(v_attribute_value);
      end loop;
      return null;
   end;
begin
   fecth_values(1, 1);
end;
```

Your where clause was wrong the `i.key` should be compared against the inputed values, not the `'v_' || i.key`, which is undeclared when you execute your stmt.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is to dynamically prepare the key for where condition.

Comment: There might be a different key in future, say productid, then that key will be configured in table and where condition should execute 'where i_productid = '. About the function accepting 2 parameters, though it accepts 2 parameters, to query the tables, always 1 parameter will be used and i want to dynamically decide (using i.key) which parameter to use. i_accountnum or i_customerid for now, may be i_productid in future. Not the case statement, how can we determine the parameter using i_key itself and pass it to the dynamic sql?

Comment: Change your approach. Make a function which will receive the `table name`, and `key value`. Map the relevant key column name and fetching parameter from your mapping table using `table name` parameter and return that value. Call this function 2 times, 3 times, as much as needed.

Comment: didn't understand what you are trying to say. The CASE statement was helpful though, thanks.